# Create a generic List from C# dll in python script

Tags: c#, python

```
var settings = new SettingsClass();
settings.SpecificValue = new List<SpecificValueClass>();
```

This is the code example in my C# project.

I have a python script which imports the .dll with this code example and I want to create this settings.SpecificValue variable within the python script.

Is it somehow possible without making a function in C# which I can call within python code.

```
public class SettingsClass
{
    public bool Timesync { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public string Timezone { get; set; }
    public List<SpecificValueClass> SpecificValue{ get; set; }
}

public class SpecificValueClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

In python I want to call it like this:

```
settings = SettingsClass() <-- this call is no problem and I can do it with a dotNet library in python
settings.SystemName = systemname
settings.Timesync = timesync
settings.Timezone = "%s//%s" % (timezone1,timezone2)
settings.SpecificValue = ... <-- not sure how to make this to create a empty List / empty whatever so I can add 2 objects of the type SpecificValueClass
```

(creating the 2 objects ob SpecificValueClass is also possible) 
So the only part that I can not get to work is the initialization of the settings.SpecificValue as it is a generic List ...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you'd have to explain how is your *.dll* loaded in *Python*. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also what *Python* (version **and** distribution) are you using?

Comment: I am using an external tool - TestComplete - which makes the loading process via CLR Bridge - not sure if this information helps? Python 3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it to work using the dotNet library from TestComplete but I guess it would be the same with the clr package from python. Just had to program the generics part myself which usually C# does with the  tags:

```
typeListOf = dotNET.System.Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1")
objType = dotNET.namespace.SpecificValueClass.zctor().GetType()
paramTypes = dotNET.System.Array.CreateInstance(dotNET.System.Type.GetType("System.Type"), 1)
paramTypes.SetValue(objType, 0)
typeListOfString = typeListOf.MakeGenericType(paramTypes)

newValue = dotNET.namespace.WattPeakValues.zctor()

newValue.ID = 1
settings.SpecificValue.Add(newValue)
```